# Run time error 1004 " file could

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on project of invoice automation, here i have designed code for that but I am facing Problem with Run time error for code showing file could not found on specific location

code is as per `Workbooks.Open ("C:\invoicesample\invoice.xlsx")` I have also tried with change location for the same but still its not working

Comment: I see that you are commenting on the other answer. Is there a specific reason as to why are you ignoring my post?

Comment: Sorry Siddharth i didnt check your comment if you have any idea please help me to out from this problem

Answer (score 0):

This is the updated Code and make sure your destination file(C:\invoicesample\invoice.xlsx) is available.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim outward As Variant
    Dim Invoice As Variant
    Dim resources As String
    Dim qty As String
    Dim Vat As String
    Dim unitprice As String
    Dim kindattn As String
    Dim name As String
    Dim address As String
    Dim city As String
    Dim r As Long
    Dim state As String
    Dim zip As String
    Dim mobileno As Variant
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim phonenumber As String
    Dim bankid As String
    Dim path As String
    Dim myfilename As String
    Dim mydate As String
    Dim servicetax As String
    Dim strfilepath As String
    Dim total As Long

    lastrow = Sheets("invoiceinfo").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    r = 6

    For r = 6 To lastrow

        If Cells(r, 21).Value = "done" Then GoTo nextrow

        outward = Sheets("Invoiceinfo").Cells(r, 3).Value
        Invoice = Sheets("invoiceinfo").Cells(r, 4).Value
        resources = Sheets("invoiceinfo").Cells(r, 6).Value
        qty = Sheets("invoiceinfo").Cells(r, 7).Value
        unitprice = Sheets("invoiceinfo").Cells(r, 8).Value
        Vat = Sheets("invoiceinfo").Cells(r, 9).Value
        servicetax = Sheets("invoiceinfo").Cells(r, 10).Value
        kindattn = Sheets("invoiceinfo").Cells(r, 12).Value
        name = Sheets("invoiceinfo").Cells(r, 13).Value
        address = Sheets("invoiceinfo").Cells(r, 14).Value
        city = Sheets("invoiceinfo").Cells(r, 15).Value
        state = Sheets("invoiceinfo").Cells(r, 16).Value
        zip = Sheets("invoiceinfo").Cells(r, 17).Value
        mobileno = Sheets("invoiceinfo").Cells(r, 18).Value
        phonenumber = Sheets("invoiceinfo").Cells(r, 19).Value
        bankid = Sheets("invoiceinfo").Cells(r, 20).Value

        Cells(r, 21).Value = "done"
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        strfilepath = "C:\invoicesample\invoice.xlsx"

        If Dir(strfilepath) = "" Then
           MsgBox " file not avilable on path ", vbCritical
        Else
            Workbooks.Open (strfilepath)
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("invoice").Activate
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("invoice").Range("D9").Value = bankid
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("invoice").Range("D11").Value = kindattn
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("invoice").Range("D12").Value = name
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("invoice").Range("D13:H14").Value = address
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("invoice").Range("D15").Value = city
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("invoice").Range("F15").Value = state
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("invoice").Range("H15").Value = zip
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("invoice").Range("H15").Value = mobileno
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Invoice").Range("D17").Value = phonenumber
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("invoice").Range("M14").Value = outward
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("invoice").Range("M15").Value = Invoice
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("invoice").Range("E20:H20").Value = resources
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("invoice").Range("J20").Value = qty
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("invoice").Range("L20").Value = unitprice
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("invoice").Range("M20").Value = total
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("invoice").Range("M38").Value = Vat
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("invoice").Range("M39").Value = servicetax

            path = "D:\contact details\"
            mydate = Date
            Date = Format(mydate, "DD_MM_YYYY")

            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=path & Invoice & "-" & Date & "-" & name & ".Xlsx"
            myfilename = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            SetAttr myfilename, vbReadOnly
            'ActiveWorkbook.PrintOut Copies:=1

            ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
        End If
nextrow:
        Next r


End Sub
```

Comment: still its showing error, can i send you complete file to have look and problem

Comment: Sure! Please share the complete file in file sharing website like dropbox and let me know the link to download it. I can have look at it.

Comment: can i send it across your email id if possible

Comment: i have sent mail on mentioned email id please check and confirm whether you received it or not

Comment: Your error is not with workbooks.open. It is with Go to statement. Just replace nextrow to nextrow: Let me edit my previous solution with the updated code.

Comment: I have checked everything now its showing file is not found on path. after that again checked but still its not working and file is in location as mentioned in code. is to code error or system error? is it folder structure issue?